# How to Exclude post from a category

Tags: categories

This is my home page code

here is a feature post section,
i want to exclude post by a category 'Collage' in this section ...

```
<?php 
$count = 1;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if($count == 1) : ?>


<div id="featurd_post">
<div class="ftrd_image">
<?php woo_get_image('image',455,245,' '.$GLOBALS['align']); ?>  </div>
<div class="fix"></div>
<div class="ftrd_entry">
<h2 class="title">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title=""><?php   the_title(); ?></a> 
</h2>
<p class="fetrd_entry"><?php dynamic_excerpt(400); ?></p>
<a href="#" title="" class="read_more">(<?php _e('&#2310;&#2327;&#2375; 
&#2346;&#2338;&#2375; ', 'shreshthbharat'); ?>)</a>
</div></div>     
<?php else : ?>

  <--- Rest of post goes here --- > 

<div class="box"><div class="post">
<h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

Comment: how are the 'featured' posts defined? is there a query before the first line of your posted section? if so, can you please post that as well?

Comment: no this is just a simple section '#featurd_post' 
i mean it's first post different from rest of all post, i want to exclude 'collage' category posts in this section.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude a category you'll need to modify the query that's running.  Do this using the query_posts() function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

First, you'll need to get the ID of the category you want to exclude:

```
$exclude_category = get_term_by('name', 'collage', 'category');
```

Then you'll need add the category exclusion to the query, and pass the new query to query_posts:

```
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'category__not_in' => array( $exclude_category) ) );
query_posts( $args );
```

Put all this right at the top of the script, just before the loop.

Hope that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be work.. I didnt wrote it but found on wordpress website.

```
 <?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-3,-8'); ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <div class="post">

 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

 <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
 <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

  <div class="entry">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>

  <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
 </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->

 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

for more details you can check this link http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category